# Do Veela have names?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter* there are Veela, women who are part human, who are so beautiful and charming that they can seduce any man. I was just curious about the fact that I can't seem to find anything about them having names. I know that goblins and giants have names from what is said in the books but the only Veela we know of is Fleurs grandmother whose name is never mentioned. As Fleurs gradnmother has offspring i assume Veela have relationships like a human. As they are part human would they also have names? What would their husbands/partners call them otherwise?

Comment: Sorry, but this question seems silly... Fleur Delacour (and her Sister) IS (partly) Veela and for sure she has a name... Why wouldn't they have no names? Giants do have names as well as centaurs, goblins or elves.. every race in the HP universe that is only deemed semi intelligent has names...

Comment: @TorstenLink They have names but they're also part human so the humans could have insisted on a name and we don't know if Fleur's grandmother has a name. I think it's likely that they do have names but this question does seem to have merit.

Comment: Well we know that giants and goblins have names but i have never heard of Veela having names. i assume they would but unlike giants and goblins they seem to be more mysterious, goblins have pushed themselves into the wizarding world and giants live in communities but veela seem to keep to themselves. I'm and curious to know what names they might have if they have names

Answer (score 5):

Well Veela are classified as beings by the ministry of magic.

A being is defined as:

> The definition of a Being is "any creature that has sufficient intelligence to understand the laws of the magical community and to bear part of the responsibility in shaping those laws".

Therefore it's not too much to presume that Veela would follow human customs of having names like Centaurs (even though they are classified as beasts, they have human intelligence). Maybe they take up names after getting married? Its all conjecture here I'm afraid.

Ultimately, there are no known full Veela who have names. At best we have Fleur's mother, Apolline Delacour.

Comment: I wouldn't let a centaur hear you saying that they follow human customs if I were you...